# Transform Set<Keyword> into String[]

Tags: java

I have an object Keyword that stores a String with the text of the keyword and a set o keywords (`Set<Keyword>`) that I need to transform into a String array. Is there a quick/easy way to do this or I need to iterate the set and add each keyword one by one?

**EDIT:**

For those asking for Keyword class:

```
@Entity
public class Keyword {

    // ...

    @Basic
    private String value;

    // ...

    // Getters & Setters

}
```

Comment: So the object actually refers to a string? Object o = "HELLO"?

Comment: Can you add more source? I don't understand the description that you provide in the opening.

Comment: What is a `Keyword`? Can you show the class?

Comment: Your title says `Set<Object>`, yet you refer to a `Set<Keyword>`.

Comment: Keyword added to question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every class that implements `Collection` intefrace (and that includes `Set`) has `toArray()` method:

```
String[] array= set.toArray(new String[0]);
```

---

In case of a set that is parametrized with some other type, e.g. `Set<Keyword>` you would have to do something like:

```
Keyword[] array= set.toArray(new Keyword[0]);
String[] stringArray= new String[array.length];

for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    stringArray[i]= array[i].getThatString();
}
```

Comment: The op mentioned a `Set<KeyWord>` not a `Set<Object>` which happens to contain Strings.

Comment: Yes, the title was incorrect. Sorry for that. And thank you for the answer. That is exactly what I thought.

Comment: Why iterate over an array of Keyword[] while you can directly iterate over the Set?

Answer (score 3):

<strike>Try this:</strike>

```
String[] arr = set.toArray(new String[set.size()]);
```

... is what I would have said, if you had a `Set<Object>`.

---

No, there is no way to directly convert a `Set<Keyword>` to a `String[]` since there is no direct relationship between `Keyword` and `String`. You will have to iterate over the set:

```
String[] arr = new String[set.size()];
int i = 0;
for (Keyword word : set)
    arr[i++] = word.toString();
```

Comment: @assylias Oops, I thought it was a `Set<Object>`.

Comment: @assylias, No, Set<KeyWord> is not a Set<String>.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/), you may use this:

```
Lists.transform(Lists.newArrayList(theSet), Functions.usingToString())
    .toArray(new String[theSet.size()])
```

And this only scratches the surface of what Guava can actually do.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using Guava but I'll take a look for future projects (and maybe this one). Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @DavidMorenoGarcía (personal opinion, mind) you should _seriously_ consider using it. As I mentioned in the comments, it is only one thing that it can do. See [here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html) for the full API. Note that it has _real_ immutable collections, _real_ IP address verification, etc etc. Go for it. Really.

Comment: Sometimes in project you cannot add extra additional dependencies and that is what Davis is saying due to which he cannot use Guava.

Comment: @GladwinB I always have trouble with the "cannot add extra additional dependencies" part; in this day and age, it just cannot be a technical argument, only a corporate policy argument; whose value is nil when developers are concerned...

Comment: @fge: I never mentioned corporate or their policy but you do need to keep they are the ones who generate our paycheck. Further more on technical grounds, do you really waana include the whole library coz it has one small functionality that you need which indeed you can implement by yourself? Remember, one more dependency is one more link in chain that needs to be considered w.r.t  security, bugs, complexity, etc.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific way to do this . You can either convert Set to Object[] using set.toArray and then iterate over the array 
or 
iterate over the set directly

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add `toString()` method to your Keyword class as shown below. Or you can use a separate transformer class/method.

```
class Keyword {
    private String value;

    Keyword(String v) {
        this.value = v;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return value;
    }
}
```

.

I would say **iterate the set and add each keyword one by one** is your best possible strategy.

```
System.out.println(toStringArray(set));
```

.

```
private static String[] toStringArray(Collection<?> set) {
    String[] arr = null;
    if (set != null) {
        arr = new String[set.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Object o : set) {
            arr[i++] = o.toString();
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
```

.

However if you really want, you can have a **dirty workaround** as shown below. Only issue here is that your keyword value cannot contain comma (`,`) as it is used by split() method.

```
String str = set.toString();
str = str.substring(1, str.length() - 1);
String[] asStringArray = str.split(",");
System.out.println(asStringArray);
```